# How can improve the android frame rate?

Tags: android, frame

I want to improve my APP's frame rate, at present, using SurfaceView. 
In method draw, there are many methods.These methods cost tiny time, maybe 3ms or 5ms, but total of them is not accepted.It is the reason why has low frame rate.
And I know if I use ndk, can make this method run faster and may be has higher frame rate, but I can't because of some reason, has any other way ? Thanks.

Comment: Your question is very generic like "my cars not fast enough - how can I make it faster?". Edit your question and present more details about what you do and why it is too slow.

Comment: Thanks your remind, I have edited the question and add the reason why it is too slow.

Comment: We need to see your code, that's the only way to advise you and finding out if things can be done better and faster.

Comment: @Snicolas, I'm sorry, the code is not allowed publish.Can you give me some direction ways? Anyway thanks.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/optimizing-view.html. General but useful. Don't neglect to remove ALL instanciations if possible, that's often the key.